# Is it possible to run Node.js commands alongside three.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, three.js

I am attempting to run node.js commands within my three.js project. Something as simple as declaring SQLite3 and initializing my database doesn't seem to be working. Ultimately I want to run UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE commands throughout game play as the user picks up items. Since node.js and three.js are both JavaScript packages, I assumed they would fit well together. There doesn't seem to be much information about this, so what I want to know is it possible to combine the two or am I wasting my time?

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var fs = require('fs');
var db = new sqlite3.Database('shopDB.db');
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Are there any messages in the console?

Comment: Well at the moment I have got ReferenceError: require is not defined 1 main.js:1:6

Comment: Are you trying to use node.js in the browser? You can't do that.

Comment: Ah ok, that would be the problem then. It is possible to run node.js in a terminal whilst three.js runs in the browser?

Comment: Sure, of course. You'll need to communicate with the node.js instance with either WebSockets or simple HTTP end points in that case. By the way, node.js is an environment for writing server systems in JavaScript (e.g. like a web server). Since you were trying to use that in the browser, it kind of sounds like you might need to take a step back and do some basic tutorials and learn a bit more about node.js before you dive in any further.

Comment: You're probably right. I haven't much experience in node.js. I do however have experience of SQLite. I have my prepared .sql file complete with tables, and inserted items, which has been stored within my .db file. Having read various tutorials, I have gone as far as to prepare the necessary insert, delete, update functions within my DB.js file and run several tests in command prompt. I thought it would be easy enough to just copy and paste these functions into my three.js. How would I begin to introduce HTTP end points within my .js file? Point me in the right direction and Ill confirm answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, you can't use node.js in the browser. If you want your browser app to talk to a database, you can expose a [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) around your database. This means exposing some HTTP endpoints to access your data.

For example, you might POST some JSON object describing some data from your browser-based app to `http://someurl/some_path` and your web server would be listening for a POST to the `/some_path` url, at which point it would read the POST data and insert a new entry into your database.

You could use [jQuery's `ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function to make requests to the API.

[This](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=3152) blog post runs through an example REST API built around a sqlite database.